# How do you post an array field with Guzzle?

Tags: php, post, guzzle

How do you post an array field with Guzzle? I have tried the following but nothing is received in the `fruits` variable.

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
$client   = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post('http://example/post', [ 
   'form_params' => [ 'fruits' => $fruits ] 
] );
```

Comment: I've tried what you've posted here, but it seems to work just fine? 

Comment: Really? Its not working for me. when i change $fruit to a string it works ok. the field is not accepting the array.

Comment: I've tested this code on my machine and it works as intended too.